# Serverless get list of local functions

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, serverless-framework-offline

**Scenario**

I'm writing unit tests for local Lambda Output. Instead of manually putting in the names of all the different lambda functions I'm wanting to dynamically generate the list.

```
sls deploy list functions
```

Will return the list of functions that are deployed to aws, but not the ones that are in the local serverless environment

**Question**

How do I get a list of functions that are local?

The help menu is useful for how to run a local function, but not to assemble a local functions list.

```
$ sls --help

Commands
* You can run commands with "serverless" or the shortcut "sls"
* Pass "--verbose" to this command to get in-depth plugin info
* Pass "--no-color" to disable CLI colors
* Pass "--help" after any <command> for contextual help

Framework
* Documentation: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/

config ........................ Configure Serverless
config credentials ............ Configures a new provider profile for the Serverless Framework
create ........................ Create new Serverless service
deploy ........................ Deploy a Serverless service
deploy function ............... Deploy a single function from the service
deploy list ................... List deployed version of your Serverless Service
deploy list functions ......... List all the deployed functions and their versions
info .......................... Display information about the service
install ....................... Install a Serverless service from GitHub or a plugin from the Serverless registry
invoke ........................ Invoke a deployed function
invoke local .................. Invoke function locally
logs .......................... Output the logs of a deployed function
metrics ....................... Show metrics for a specific function
package ....................... Packages a Serverless service
plugin ........................ Plugin management for Serverless
plugin install ................ Install and add a plugin to your service
plugin uninstall .............. Uninstall and remove a plugin from your service
plugin list ................... Lists all available plugins
plugin search ................. Search for plugins
print ......................... Print your compiled and resolved config file
remove ........................ Remove Serverless service and all resources
rollback ...................... Rollback the Serverless service to a specific deployment
rollback function ............. Rollback the function to a specific version
slstats ....................... Enable or disable stats

Platform (Beta)
* The Serverless Platform is currently in experimental beta. Follow the docs below to get started.
* Documentation: https://serverless.com/platform/docs/

emit .......................... Emits an event to a running Event Gateway
login ......................... Login or sign up for the Serverless Platform
logout ........................ Logout from the Serverless Platform
run ........................... Runs the Event Gateway and the Emulator
```

Comment: did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: @RMK We ended up switching to [SAM local](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli) which worked a whole lot better for that team as a whole. GL!

Answer (score 5):

```
serverless info
```

This gives the following:

```
Service Information
service: <>
stage: <>
region: <>
stack: <>
api keys:
  <>
endpoints:
  <>
functions:
  <List of function names>
```

Comment: your self-answer works for me! please mark your own answer as the correct one.

Comment: I am a different person than who asked the Qs.

Comment: This only works with remote functions, It doesn't work on local funcations